# Не работает JQeuery на локальной странице

Tags: javascript

Создал простенькую страницу и пытаюсь исполнить на ней JS скрипт, но тот не подаёт признаков жизни.
Хотя на том же https://jsfiddle.net/Blunt71/h82fkgz4/1/ всё работает.
В консоле ошибок нет... [image: Скрин консоли]

```js
$(".menu-button").click(function(){
    $(".menu-panel").toggleClass("menu-hiden"); return false;
});
```

```css
aside {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
}

nav {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50px;
}

.menu-button {
    height: 25px;
    width: 35px;
    margin: 30px 0 0 7px;
    display: block;
    background: #000;
}

.menu-panel {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 0 0 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f6f8f9;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: translateX(0%);
    z-index: 99;
}

.menu-hiden {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/aside.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <aside>
        <nav>
            <a class="menu-button" href="#"></a>
        </nav>
        <div class="menu-panel"></div>
    </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: во-первых, вставь тег `<script>` в конец `body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у тебя скрипт пытается найти элемент, которого еще не существует. Перекинь вниз скрипты.

либо:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // твой код
})
```

Comment: Алекс Данилин, огромное тебе спаибо. Я сегодня всю голову на этом сломал.

Comment: > Я сегодня всю голову на этом сломал - добро пожаловать в волшебный мир джаваскрипт!